# is it still possible to submit apps using xcode 3?

Tags: xcode3.2

I really want to develop apps but i cant afford a new computer (I have a g4). Is it still possible to do this on xcode 3? or do you need xcode 4?

Answer (score 0):

This is less a question of the Xcode version as of the SDK compatibility.

If you intend to develop for OSX, then 3.2 will be fine.

If you intend to develop for iOS, then you will definitely need an Intel Mac as the iOS SDK only runs under Intel (regardless of Xcode 3 or Xcode 4).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any limitation on the Store accepting apps written for SDK 3 at this point, though I could be wrong, but it really would be better for you to upgrade.

Not only will it allow you to develop for the newer SDK's, it will also be easier to find the solutions you need to do things, and examples are mostly going to be for XCODE 4 these days. XCODE 3 and XCODE4 do have some fundamental differences in UI and other things.

Trust me, XCODE 4 does make some things much simpler, code signing etc for one.

I know Apple hardware is relatively expensive, but if you can scrape up $300-$400 for a used mac mini then you can VCN to it from your laptop if you wish, it would be a better option all around.

Not to mention the 4.0 and 5.0 SDK's do add some features that make coding simpler in some ways etc.